# Make a count down timer from an Int input?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, time, nsdate

So I want the user to be able to input the number of days(an `Int`) in the future and click a button to start a count down. I want the output to be an `Int` of days until the date. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have date after `n` days and I call it `dateAfterNDays` so the solution will be using [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/).

```
components(_:fromDate:toDate:options:)
```

method and finding the difference using `.Day` component. Example as follows:

```
let dateDifference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
                               .components(.Day,
                                           fromDate: today,    // currentDate
                                           toDate: dateAfterNDays!,    // date for countdown
                                           options: [])

let diffInDays = dateDifference.day   // Expected days
```